# What is the type of verb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, passive-voice, active-voice

In the following sentence, *to be answered* belongs to which verb tense?

> What we mentioned just now is, by the way, a very important question **to be answered** – it is like an “acid test” for any astrological doctrine.

#### Reference

[K.S. Krishnamurti in “Hindu Astrology vs Western Astrology”](https://www.learnastrologyonline.in/blog/hindu-astrology-vs-western-astrology)

Comment: Hi Safir: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask :)

Comment: to be + past participle is called a passive infinitive and it does not have a tense.

Comment: So: the passive infinitive _construction_ (not _tense_).

Answer (score 2):

## No inﬂection means no tense

Like person and number, the tense of a verb is a simple matter of
morphological inﬂection. But *to be answered* is an **uninﬂected**
*to*-infinitive. It is not a finite verb at all, but a nonfinite one.

That means that the verb *be* is not tensed at all here, and so it has no
tense whatsoever, just like it similarly has no inﬂection for person or
number.

The verb *be* is here used in its base, uninﬂected form. To be tensed, it
would need to be inﬂected for person, number, and time, and so be one of
*am, art, is, are, was, wert, were* instead of just plain *be*.

Here is the table showing how these vary with *be*:

| Example | Tense | Person | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| to *be* happy | ***none!*** | *none!* | *none!* |
| *being* happy | ***none!*** | *none!* | *none!* |
| I *am* happy | **present** | first | singular |
| Thou *art* happy | **present** | second | singular |
| He/she/it *is* happy | **present** | third | singular |
| We/you/they *are* happy | **present** | first/second/third | plural |
| I/he *was* happy | **past** | first/third | singular |
| Thou *wert* happy | **past** | second | singular |
| We/you/they *were* happy | **past** | first/second/third | plural |

In all but a few remaining dialects of English, the *thou* forms are now
archaic. They are today found mainly in older literature from the Early
Modern English period or in more recent works emulating the same such as
prayers, hymns, and poetry, or in dialogue representing speakers from that
historical period.

That means the answer to your question is "None", or "it's not".

Comment: @Lambie Explain the meaning of what particular thing?

Comment: @Lambie "Passive infinitive" is not a tense. He asked for the tense. There is none. Compare *to be spectacled* and *to be happy*: no tense whatsoever.